# Getting 400 Bad Request when trying to upload a video with youtube API v3 for c#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Using the following code:

```
    public async Task<YouTubeService> GetYouTubeService(string userEmail)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[]
                {
                    YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
                    YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload,
                    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly
                },
                userEmail,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        return youtubeService;
    }

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };

            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
            var filePath = @"c:\temp\nouvelair.mp4";

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet.status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }


    public void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                break;
            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
            case UploadStatus.Completed:
                Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
        }
    }
```

---

In the function videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged, at first I get the status of video starting then right after I get a status of failed with following exception:

Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Can you capture the http request with either wireshark or fiddler and post it too?

Comment: I installed fiddler, but can't see any request in it when executing my c# code in debug.

Comment: Is it https? If so, fiddler requires further configuration to show the request

Comment: After enabling https in fiddler, I got the following:

see the following link http://www.codesend.com/view/a66bf5d5467e24b91eed002dca9896c8/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set values in a part that doesn't exist; you have, as your part argument:

```
snippet.status
```

But you need to delimit parts with a comma, not a dot:

```
var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
```